# How to click a link automatically if it contains particular keyword

Tags: javascript, applescript

There is a web-page that has bunch of links.
All of these links will be worked with javascript's onclick function.
Each link has arguments that'll be past to function to decide the landing page.

In this case, how can I write applescript to jump to particular page if the link always have the same keyword.

I'm using script editor to automate this with Safari on MaxOS Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chrome responds better to Javascript commands.

```
set myKeyword to "questions"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set URL to "http://stackoverflow.com/"
        delay 3
        set num_links to (execute javascript "document.links.length") - 1
        repeat with i from 0 to num_links
            set myLink to execute javascript "document.links[" & i & "].href"
            if myLink contains myKeyword then
                execute javascript "document.links[" & i & "].click()"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```